# Cusum exit dialog in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I want to create a custom exit dialog box with three images that images are fetching from server. Dialog is show if i click back button. Dialog is showed to me but images that are fetched from server are not shown, default images are showing. Image url is successfully getting from server. If i place that url in my imageView an exception is generated:

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.madnanijaz.labassignment1, PID: 2967
>                                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
>                                                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:27)
>                                                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:22)
>                                                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:383)
>                                                                                            at com.example.madnanijaz.labassignment1.MainActivity$7.onResponse(MainActivity.java:181)
>                                                                                            at com.example.madnanijaz.labassignment1.MainActivity$7.onResponse(MainActivity.java:170)

My code of Back Pressed button is:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    //Fetching Images(Adds from server)
    fetchingAddsFromServer();

    //CustomAlertDialog

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new 
   AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    View view= 
  LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,null);

    builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setView(view);
    builder.show();

   // AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
    //alertDialog.show();

}

  private void fetchingAddsFromServer() {

    StringRequest request= new StringRequest(URL, new 
    Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object= new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray=object.getJSONArray("slots");

                    JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Url 
     is:"+jsonObject.getString("imgurl"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               // String ImgURI=jsonObject.getString("imgurl");

  Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(jsonObject.getString("imgurl")).into(c 
       losingDialogImageTwo);

                //}

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    queue.add(request);
```

I think its an error of custom layout.I have one ImageView in main screen. if i use Glide with that it is working fine but if a use Glide with custom layout of dialog it gives me this error that is mentioned.

Comment: Hello! Where is your closingDialogImageTwo? I dont see it instance with the view, maybe it is the null that broke your app.

Answer (score 0):

The following error:

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.madnanijaz.labassignment1, PID: 2967
>                                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
>                                                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:27)
>                                                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:22)
>                                                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:383)
>                                                                                            at com.example.madnanijaz.labassignment1.MainActivity$7.onResponse(MainActivity.java:181)
>                                                                                            at com.example.madnanijaz.labassignment1.MainActivity$7.onResponse(MainActivity.java:170)

happens because you're trying to loading the image to `closingDialogImageTwo` with this:

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(jsonObject.getString("imgurl")).into(c losingDialogImageTwo);
```

but you haven't initialize the View yet. Because the image is inside the custom view for the dialog, you need to initialize it after you inflating the view. Which is after the following code:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,null);
```

with this:

```
ImageView closingDialogImageTwo = view.findViewById(R.id.your_image_id);
```

You need to load the image only after your `fetchingAddsFromServer()` method finished fetching the image because its asynchronous behaviour.

To summarize, you need to move your AlertDialog creation inside the `fetchingAddsFromServer` like this:

```
private void fetchingAddsFromServer() {
    StringRequest request= new StringRequest(URL, new 
    Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

          ...  
          // assuming you got the image.
          String imageUrl = jsonObject.getString("imgurl");

          showDialogWithImage(imageUrl);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    queue.add(request);
}


private void showDialogWithImage(String imageUrl) {
  final AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,null);

  ImageView closingDialogImageTwo = view.findViewById(R.id.your_image_id);

  Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
       .load(imageUrl).into(closingDialogImageTwo);

  builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setView(view);
    builder.show();
}
```